# Convert JWT token created by Java JWT in python

Tags: jwt, decode, jjwt, pyjwt

I have received a JWT token created by a java program using jjwt module.
Now, when I try to verify the token using pyjwt, it throws exception.

```
import jwt token
token='eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMDAiLCJyb2xlcyI6IkJVU0lORVNTVVNFUiIsIm1vZGUiOiJzdG9yZWFwcCIsImlhdCI6MTQ5NDg1ODk4MCwiZXhwIjoxNDk0ODY0OTgwfQ.ckFnGv1NT-Ui2S90DNr50YoHSXc1ZLBNnEErnGMWL-E'
secret ='123456AB' 
jwt.decode(token,secret,algorithms='HS256')
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
>      File
>   "/Applications/anaconda/envs/modulename/lib/python3.5/site-packages/jwt/api_jwt.py",
>   line 64, in decode
>       options, **kwargs)   File "/Applications/anaconda/envs/modulename/lib/python3.5/site-packages/jwt/api_jws.py",
>   line 116, in decode
>       key, algorithms)   File "/Applications/anaconda/envs/modulename/lib/python3.5/site-packages/jwt/api_jws.py",
>   line 186, in _verify_signature
>       raise DecodeError('Signature verification failed') jwt.exceptions.DecodeError: Signature verification failed

If i use the same token in jwt.io, with base64 encrypted option checked, it seems to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because when Java created the token it thought the plain text you used as a secret was base64 encoded. I am assuming Java was expecting the string secret to be base64 encoded version of some binary. Try base64 decoding the secret before decoding jwt.

```
import base64
jwt.decode(token,base64.b64decode(secret))

#The token in your question was expired so I ended up passing verify expiration = False
jwt.decode(token,base64.b64decode(secret), options={ 'verify_exp': False})

{u'iat': 1494858980, u'exp': 1494864980, u'sub': u'100', u'roles': u'BUSINESSUSER', u'mode': u'storeapp'}
```

Comment: It worked like a breeze! Thanks. The java jjwt package do not clearly mentions that the secret key we provide is assumed to be a base64 encoded string.

Comment: Glad to help, if this answer solved your problem please mark it as accepted by clicking the check mark next to the answer. see: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work for more information

Answer (score 0):

You may try to verify the signature of the incoming token in your Python application **using the same `SecretKey`** as you have used in your Java application.